# Disable appear link on hover

Tags: html, css

The ahref link under the h2 tag only appears when you hover over that place, otherwise it disappears. How do I remove the disappearing behavior ? I want to make it normal and appear all the time.

Here is the Html

```
<div class="doctor_name">
  <h1> {{doctor.name}} </h1>

  <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;"> {{doctor.specialization.name}} </h2>
 <h2> <a href="/clinic/{{clinic.slug}}/">{{clinic.name}}</a></h2>
  <h2 style="color: grey;"> {{doctor.clinic.address_normal}} </h2>
```

Here is the css

```
.doctor_name > h2 {
    margin-top: -1px;
    font-size: 1.20em;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.doctor_name{
    width: 303px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -234px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.doctor_name > h1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 2.2em;
}
```

Comment: how does a link disappear....

Comment: do you want it to be underlined ALL the time?? some different color too or something?

Comment: It's kind of invisible and only shows when I hover that place. I'm guessing it's the text color that is white on a white background and it becomes green when I hover my mouse over that place

Comment: @HarisB. inspect HTML and resolved CSS styles (usually it also says from which CSS file properties are inherited and applied)

Comment: yea... if it is white on a white background just add `h2 > a{ color: green; text-decoration: underline; }`

Comment: Please add screenshot

Comment: @CayceK Thanks. It worked! You can put it as an answer and I can tick mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:
Link is white on a white background.

Solution:
Give it css coloring and decoration to stand out within the associated position. Obviously once you change the color it will be visible no matter, but you are more than welcome to change/add more stylings!

```
h2 > a{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
h2 > a{ 
    color:red; 
    text-decoration:underline; 
}
```

If it does not work, try this

```
h2 > a{ 
    color:red!important; 
    text-decoration: underline!important; 
}
```

Comment: just a quick comment on !important... if the first one doesn't work do not do important.. ever... be more specific to the associated. There is no reason to use important unless there is an inline style and then you have a whole other set of problems.... just saying...

Comment: @  Cayce K `!important` **we use to override the existing css property.**
so in the above case  i am not sure what and all css are used.
also please **educate me** what set of of problems we will face if we are using `!important`thanks in advance.

Comment: As a very strict practice I refuse to use !important. No matter what you know or don't know about the CSS you can always get around using !important UNLESS the CSS is set to inline. In those cases it is much less likely for you to be able to avoid it. !important creates a number of problems when you expect something. If we use your important and want to later do `h2 > a.pink{ color: pink; }` we would EXPECT it to be pink. In reality this has a greater value than the previously declared, but now that the !important is there it fails and we have to add !important to ours to continue. etcetc.